# Reference or Cheat Sheet of biblatex

Tags: biblatex, tutorials

Today I switched to `biblatex` and found it amazing. I've already skimmed the manual of `biblatex`. I wonder if any Reference or Cheat Sheet of `biblatex` is available. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the book by Herbert Voss, but in German only so far, as I know

Comment: This is an open feature request - we really need a "quick start" guide as the manual is a (comprehensive) beast. Anybody volunteering to help with this is most welcome ...

Comment: Is http://heim.ifi.uio.no/dag/latex-links/biblatex-guide.pdf useful?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That link does indeed look very useful though I would hesitate to describe 39 pages as a 'cheat sheet'! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maïeul Rouquette has written a [openbook](http://geekographie.maieul.net/Xe-LaTeX-applique-aux-sciences) (in french) on LaTeX for social sciences. It references how to use `BibLaTeX` to fullfil the very specific requests of social science bibliographies.

As I mentioned, the book is in french. There is also a project of translation in Italian. The book is on [Github](https://github.com/maieul/latexhumain), so someone might translate it in English someday.

(I don't know if you read french or italian, so I apology if my answer does not help you).

**Edit:** [This intro from ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/07/31/getting-started-with-biblatex.html) is a good Cheat Sheet.

Comment: LOL `:)` The book has the subtitle: "The only book on LaTeX without one single equation!" `+1`